# Pomless Tycho build in Eclipse with inherited Maven dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tycho

I'm currently working on creating a Maven-Tycho build environment for a relatively large RCP project. The Maven build is already completing successfully, but I'm having trouble removing all the errors from the projects when opening all the sub-projects in the Eclipse IDE.
One of the problems that is most common is, that a MANIFEST.MF contains a Require-Bundle line that cannot be found. This is mostly because I'm using the tycho-pomless extension to reduce the number of pom files I need to maintain.
So the error that happens is, that it cannot find a dependency in the Manifest, because the project should inherit it from the parent-pom. Because it is a pomless build though, the temporary pom for the project is only existing while building the project with tycho-maven. This means that eclipse does not seem aware of the inheritance of the dependency.

I've created a minimal example [HERE](https://github.com/DarioRomano/Tycho-Maven-Pomless-Example).

If you open this workspace with an Eclipse IDE you can see, that there are errors and the following lines in App.java have errors:

```
import com.github.oxo42.stateless4j.conversion.ParameterConversion;

 ParameterConversion.validate(null,null);
```

The required dependency is in the parent pom in the root directory of the workspace:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.oxo42</groupId>
    <artifactId>stateless4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The dependency is also in the Manifest of module 1, but it cannot be found in the Eclipse IDE.

If you try to build the project with Maven from a shell, you will notice that the dependency inheritance is honored, even without test.module1 having a pom file and the build succeeds.

So the current state is: CLI Maven build is working, but Eclipse IDE cannot resolve the dependencies correctly making development a bit of a mess.

Is there a way around this, or will I just have to create a pom file for those specific modules?

Comment: For Eclipse plugins (which you build with Tycho) the dependencies are specified in `MANIFEST.MF` and resolved from the target platform that is set in the preferences _Plug-in Development > Target Platform_. The `pom.xml` is only for building and the dependencies are resolved by Tycho since Maven does not understands OSGi.

Comment: Your minimal example (https://github.com/DarioRomano/Tycho-Maven-Pomless-Example) does not exist or is not public.

Comment: @howlger Thanks for the heads up, it should be public now.

Comment: [These regular Maven dependencies are ignored when using Tycho](https://github.com/DarioRomano/Tycho-Maven-Pomless-Example/blob/main/pom.xml#L17-L29) (Maven resolves dependencies on compile time to a flat classpath vs. in Tycho/OSGi there is no flat classpath and plugins/bundles can be installed, started, stopped and uninstalled also at runtime). You need to specify a [Eclipse target platform](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTargetPlatform/article.html).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Tycho should be using the stateless4j dependency since it's an OSGI bundle, and I've set the `pomDependencies -> consider` in the tycho target-platform-configuration plugin in the parent pom, as stated [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform#.22POM_dependencies_consider.22:~:text=OSGi%20bundles%20from%20Maven%20repositories%20can%20be%20added%20to%20the%20target%20platform%20in%20the%20following%20way%3A).
It should therefore already create a target platform, and add the dependency to it. My problem is just that it is not recognized in Eclipse.

Comment: It seems to be missing in your current active target platform: in the preferences in _Plug-in Development > Target Platform_.

Comment: As I understand it Eclipse doesn't know about the target platform that Tycho creates. To get Eclipse to work it needs a target platform that lists all the dependencies directly.

Comment: @greg-449 I see, so the only way to make Eclipse recognize it would be to actually create the pom files and import the dependencies as normal maven dependencies I guess?

Comment: plug-in dependencies must be in the target platform (or plug-ins in the workspace)

Comment: But there is no way to add Maven dependencies (even plug-in) ones to the target platform without using [this](https://xn--lubisoft-0za.gmbh/en/articles/using-maven-artifacts-in-pde-rcp-and-tycho-builds/), right? Unfortunately I'm only using Eclipse Mars because the actual project I'm working on is a legacy project that I haven't been able to upgrade to the latest version of Eclipse yet.

Comment: That should not a problem since the latest versions of Eclipse and of Tycho support older Java and Eclipse versions.